# How to display multiple div in one click in angular.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have html like this

```
   <div ng-controller="ClientCtrl">

        <div ng-show="shows">hello</div>

        <div ng-show="show">world</div>

        <button ng-click="show=!show">click</button>

     </div>
```

When I click on click button I am able to show second div (World ) . But I want to show both div when I click on click button. How to do it.?

Comment: Exactly i waht to do that second div contain two children  div like this <div>welcome to world</div><div>hello to world </div> ...so when i click on click button i want to show first div and second children div of the second div..... so out put should be hello hello to world ...

Answer (score 2):

If the divs need to show on different variables, then you can try this:

```
<button ng-click="show=!show;shows=!shows">click</button>
```

Or a function in the controller. But do they really need to display on different variables?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<div ng-show="show">hello</div>

<div ng-show="show">world</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/WKvAaX its similar to @karaxuna